# gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'androidModelId' running XCTests on Firebase Test Lab

Tags: ios, gcloud, xctest, firebase-test-lab

Following the instructions for [Test with the gcloud CLI on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/ios/command-line), after building my app for testing and saving all test data in a zip file, I execute the command

```
gcloud firebase test ios run \
    --test MyTests.zip \
    --device model=iphone7,version=12.1,locale=it_IT,orientation=portrait
```

But, after successfull upload of tests on Firebase, I get this error:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'androidModelId'
```

It seems that `gcloud` is saerching for the `'androidModelId'` attribute (but since I'm running tests on iOS it can't find it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to be a bug when gcloud wants to report to you that the device dimensions are invalid. In your case iphone7:12.1 is not a supported device. iphone7:12.0 would be. Please run

```
gcloud firebase test ios models list
```

to see a list of supported devices and versions.

This should work:

```
gcloud firebase test ios run \
    --test MyTests.zip \
    --device model=iphone7,version=12.0,locale=it_IT,orientation=portrait
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in the next gcloud release on Tuesday, 7/09/2019.